# Syntax to let PowerShell read an object name based on current month name

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am trying to let PowerShell filter a number of objects from a cmdlet and pick an object that has a specific name format.

The name format is always going to be same like below:
current Month Name + Year + Workstations

For example the format for current month looks like below:
August 2021 Workstations

I tried the below but didn't succeed getting the desired output.

```
$currentMonth = 
    (Get-UICulture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName((Get-Date).Month.ToString())
$LatestSUG = 
    Get-CMSoftwareUpdateGroup | 
        Select-Object LocalizedDisplayName  | 
            Where-Object -Property LocalizedDisplayName -EQ '$currentMonth'
```

The cmdlet is `Get-CMSoftwareUpdateGroup`
The object name I am trying to filter is `LocalizedDisplayName`

Thanks very much for any help on this.

Comment: You don't need the `Select-Object` and you should use `-match` instead of `-eq`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead for equality you should check if the `LocalizedDisplayName` matches the `$CurrentMonth`  ... like this maybe:

```
$currentMonth = 
    (Get-UICulture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName((Get-Date).Month.ToString())
$LatestSUG = 
    Get-CMSoftwareUpdateGroup | 
        Where-Object -Property LocalizedDisplayName -Match $currentMonth
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into this question. It helped ! Sorry I came back late.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the single quote around $currentMonth and see if that works better for you.

```
$currentMonth = (Get-UICulture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName((Get-Date).Month.ToString())
    
$LatestSUG = Get-CMSoftwareUpdateGroup | Select-Object LocalizedDisplayName | Where-Object -Property LocalizedDisplayName -match $currentMonth
```

Comment: How would that help if the `LocalizedDisplayName` is actually much more than just the `$CurrentMonth` and you use the comparison operator `-eq`?  ;-)

Comment: When you use `-like` you have to add at least a `*` in front and in the end to get the result you want. ;-)

Comment: Fair enough, on the phone and missed that bit as well as messed the formatting up. Changed to match

Comment: Yes, I know... ;-)